# Displaying All records in a dataset in .csv File

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable, dataset

I have a VB.net program that runs a query.  The query will at time pull 10's of thousands of records.  As of now I have the query reporting to reportviewer and then I have a second button on the form that exports the the dataset to a .csv file.  This all works as advertised, however it is not displaying all of the records.  If I run the query without storing the info in the dataset, I get over 1,000 results.

When I run the program, I'm only getting 568 results.  My assumption is this info is too big using the "Fill" command within the program.  How can I alter it to display ALL of the records in the dataset, either in the reportviewer, or when the "export" button is selected.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT        Invoice_Tb.Customer_First_Name AS firstname, Invoice_Tb.Customer_Last_Name AS lastname, Invoice_Tb.Customer_Address AS add1, Invoice_Tb.City, 
                         Invoice_Tb.Customer_State AS State, LEFT(Invoice_Tb.ZIP_Code, 5) AS ZIP, Invoice_Tb.Customer_Email_Address AS [Email Address], 
                         Invoice_Tb.Vehicle_Mileage AS [Vehicle Mileage], Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Date AS [Date Of Service], Invoice_Tb.Store_Number, @startdate AS Start_Date, 
                         @enddate AS End_Date
FROM            Invoice_Detail_Tb INNER JOIN
                         Invoice_Tb ON Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Number = Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Number AND Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date = Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Date
WHERE        (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Store_Category_Code = 'FS') AND (Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102) AND CONVERT(Datetime, 
                         @enddate, 102)) AND (Invoice_Tb.Reminder_Mail_Flag = 'Y')
```

Here is my button code to pull the results to the report viewer:

```
Me.Invoice_TbTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataDeliveryServiceDataSet.Invoice_Tb, startdatepicker.Value, enddatepicker.Value)


        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Here is my "Export" to csv button code:

```
Dim str As New StringBuilder

        For Each dr As DataRow In Me.DataDeliveryServiceDataSet.Invoice_Tb

            For Each field As Object In dr.ItemArray

                str.Append(field.ToString & ",")

            Next

            str.Replace(",", vbNewLine, str.Length - 1, 1)

        Next



        Try

            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\temp\testcsv.csv", str.ToString, False)

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show("Write Error")

        End Try
```

Any idea how I can get all of the records to display?

Comment: You really should be using a CSV library like [`FileHelpers`](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) instead of all this `StringBuilder` work (which may very well produce invalid CSV when a field contains a `,`...)

Comment: It's displaying the exact same output as the reportviewer... so it has to be tied to the dataset, not the stringbuilder...

Comment: Try to change you `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` and check if the missing records are now retrieved. By the way 1000 records are absolutely not a problem for DataSet.Fill.

Comment: Same problem.  The query runs fine and returns all of the results on it's own... When pulled by the dataset it doesn't return all of them.

Comment: I suppose that when you say 'the query runs fine' you mean running the query in Sql Management Studio manually setting the parameter. If so, another check you could try is to remove the where condition on the dates and verify if now the records retrieved are the same

Comment: Removing the where clause would make the dataset WAY to big... there are 100's of thousands of records in the table.  Yes, running the query in the management studio returns the correct results.